# Clone at certain timestamp git

Tags: git

How can I clone from a git repo for a certain timestamp?

For instance cloning everything in a dev branch up until a set unix timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You can limit the depth of the history, but then it's not a clone.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try

> git checkout "@{10 minutes ago}"

Comment: Clone always clones the whole repository, that's the architecture of Git. However, there is the parameter --depth, with which you can clone a number of the latest commits. But then, the clone isn't really a clone from the source repository, and you can't execute actions like push, fetch, clone etc. from that shallow clone.

Comment: @Botto, @dunni: There was proposal to extend and improve shallow clone to 1.) allow specifying revision or date as a cut-off point (instead of number of commits)  2.) making shallow clone more full-featured repository.  But as far as I know no code materialized yet; at least nothing that got merged in.  *Just FYI.*